# Kubernetes Cluster - automatically scheduling your cluster

Tags: kubernetes, containers, ibm-cloud

I have a question regarding Kubernetes Cluster - I've been dealing with IBM Cloud service in particular.

I was actually thinking if it was possible to automatically scheduling cluster to shut down for a certain period of time and what is the procedure to do this?

For example, if I don't use my machines in the evening, I wonder if I can shut them down and restart them again in the early morning.
Thanks a lot for your support,
Giulio

Comment: Are you able to switch off the machines composing the cluster?

Comment: @NicolaBen: what do you mean exactly? What I would like to do is to automate the operating scheduling of clusters, in order to be charged only for the hours the cluster is up and running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot automatically schedule a cluster to shut down.

You can manually scale up or down a worker pool. You could also do some custom scripting if you wanted to do that using the IKS API: https://containers.bluemix.net/swagger-api/